# objective c - does not read utf-8 encoded file

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to display some japanese text on the ios simulator and an ipod touch. The text is read from an XML file. The header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

When the text is in english, it displays fine. However, when the text is Japanese, it comes out as an unintelligible mishmash of single-byte characters.

I have tried saving the file specifically as unicode using TextEdit. I'm using NSXMLParser to parse the data. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is the parsing code

```
   // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSString *xmlFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questionsutf8.xml"];
    NSString *xmlFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[xmlFileContents UTF8String] length:[xmlFileContents lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                   

    XMLReader *xmlReader = [[XMLReader alloc] init];

    [xmlReader parseXMLData: data];
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use for loading the file into the `NSXMLParser`?

Comment: You might want to replace your use of the deprecated `stringWithContentsOfFile:` with `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`. Perhaps your file doesn't have a BOM indicating that it is in fact UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, a BOM is optional for UTF-8. But if there is none, stringWithContentsOfFile: can't look for it to determine if a file's contents is UTF-8 or some other 8-bit encoding, such as ISO-8859-*. Using dataWithContentsOfFile: avoids that difficulty because NSData doesn't know or care about encoding - it's just a bag of bytes - and NSXMLParser understands the "encoding" attribute in the <?xml ...> prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should verify with TextWrangler (free from the Mac app store or barebones.com) that your XML file truly is UTF-8 encoded.

Second, try creating xmlFileContents with +stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:, explicitly specifying UTF-8 encoding. Or, even better, bypass the intermediate string entirely, and create data with +dataWithContentsOfFile:.

Comment: Nice. I had just found the stringWithContentsOfFile, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`stringWithContentsOfFile:` is a deprecated method. It does not do encoding detection unless the file contains the appropriate byte order mark, otherwise it interprets the file as the default C string encoding (the encoding returned by the `+defaultCStringEncoding` method). Instead, you should use the non-deprecated [and encoding-detecting] method [`stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJDDJEF).

You can use it like this:

```
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSError *error;
NSString *xmlFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath
                                                  usedEncoding:&enc
                                                         error:&error];

if (xmlFileContents == nil)
{
    NSLog (@"%@", error);
    return;
}
```